# Is there any bus or train that travels directly from Vienna to Budapest airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, vienna, bud

I want to buy a ticket to travel directly to Budapest airport from Vienna because I don't like changing trains again inside the city. It would be great to have an option to go directly to the airport but I cannot find one.

I know some options I may choose from ÖBB but I was interested to check for Hungarian options as well if any.

Comment: Since there is no train station at the Budapest airport, it will be very difficult to find a direct train from Vienna :-)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo aha didnt know that, maybe there is not any then but at least to be as close as possible to the airport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flixbus offers 2 buses a day at 5:25am and 5:30pm. So if you're not arriving shortly before, you have 3 options.

1. (The cheapest) Take the local bus (route 100) to the Nepliget bus station and catch a Flixbus there to Vienna.
2. (Dlightly more expensive) Get the express bus (route 200) to downtown and transfer to the blue line to Nepliget and then take the Flixbus to Vienna.
3. Take the express bus downtown, take the red line to Budapest-Keleti and then take the train to Vienna.

When I made this same trip (Budapest-Wien) on 7/18, we took the Flixbus from Nepliget to Vienna. I would highly recommend it based on speed/safety/price!

Comment: Great answer and welcome to Travel Stack Exchange ! I did a bit of an edit, just to make the format a bit more open.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to be incorrect: there is no direct bus from the airport to Népliget, and the numbers are mixed up too. 100E is the express bus to the center, from where you have to take the metro to go back to Népliget in the direction you just came from, so it's actually slower in this case. 200E is the slower bus going to the nearest metro station from where you can take the metro to Népliget., so for you it's actually faster.

Answer (score 1):

When you plan your route, Google Maps suggest this [Flixbus thing](https://shop.flixbus.at/search?departureCity=1394&arrivalCity=1795&route=Vienna-Budapest&rideDate=29.08.2018&adult=1&_locale=at&wt_eid=2153549293330668216&wt_t=1535492979764&affiliate=%28not%20set%29%2C&_ga=2.116920005.2122504147.1535492936-1885805022.1535492936), which seems to have direct buses from "Wien Erdberg" to "Budapest Flughafen".

Answer (score 0):

I took the bus from Budapest to Vienna and we stopped at Budapest Airport. I assume the bus also stops there on the opposite way.